# A circular swimming pool has a diameter of 24 ft, the sides are 5 ft high, and the depth of the water is 4 ft

Tags: integration

A circular swimming pool has a diameter of 24 ft, the sides are 5 ft high, and the depth of the water is 4 ft. How much work is required to pump all of the water out over the side? (Use the fact that water weighs 62.5 lb/ft3)

The textbooks answer 1.06 x 10^6 J but I got 3.3 x 10^6 J. I feel the textbook is wrong because it didnt multiply by 9.8 m/s^2 to get the force of one disk before integrating. Can anyone confirm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 62.5 is the *Weight* so the 9.8 already comes included in that number. Besides, 9.8 is in meters per second squared and the units would have to be converted to feet per second.
Hope this helps